# Facial feature points using flandmark library - MATLAB r2013d

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction

**I want to find facial feature points using [flandmark](https://github.com/uricamic/flandmark) library. But I get this compilation error.**

As instructed I've tried to compile `flandmark_compilemex.m`.

After compiling it shows the following error:

```
Warning: MEX could not find the library "flandmark_static" specified with -l option. 
     MEX looked for a file with one of the names: 
           flandmark_static.lib 
           libflandmark_static.lib 
     MEX looked for the library in the following directories: 
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\LIB\amd64 
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64 
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64 
           C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64 
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\mfc\lib 
           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\lib 
           C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft 
           ../bin7/libflandmark/Release 

Creating library
    C:\Users\Revathy\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_dVbrg8\templib.x
and object
    C:\Users\Revathy\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_dVbrg8\templib.exp 
flandmark_detector_mex.obj: error LNK2019:
    unresolved external symbol
        "int __cdecl flandmark_detect(struct _IplImage *,int *,struct model_struct *,double *,int *)"
        (?flandmark_detect@@YAHPEAU_IplImage@@PEAHPEAUmodel_struct@@PEAN1@Z)
    referenced in function mexFunction 
C:\OpenCV2.3\build\bin\flandmark-master\flandmark-master\matlab_toolbox\mex\flandmark_detector.mexw64:
    fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013B\BIN\MEX.PL:
    Error: Link of
        'C:\OpenCV2.3\build\bin\flandmark-master\flandmark-master\matlab_toolbox\mex\flandmark_detector.mexw64'
    failed. 

Unable to complete successfully.

Error in flandmark_compilemex (line 79)
    eval(['mex -O -largeArrayDims ./mex/flandmark_detector_mex.cpp -I../libflandmark/'
include libflandmark cvlibs ' -output ../matlab_toolbox/mex/flandmark_detector']);
```

I don't know how to compile the library files `flandmark_static` in matlab. Anyone please suggest me step by step installation of the library.

Comment: Could you show the steps you have done so far, please. The exact commands you run, the output from each command etc.

Comment: I downloaded the flanmark lib files online and compiled the flandmark_compilemex.m as instructed [i already have opencv 2.3.0 in c:\] I got the above metioned warning with the following error.
 
******************
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in flandmark_compilemex (line 79)
    eval(['mex -O -largeArrayDims ./mex/flandmark_detector_mex.cpp -I../libflandmark/'
    include libflandmark cvlibs ' -output ../matlab_toolbox/mex/flandmark_detector'])

******************

Comment: Yes, but I expected you to update your question with step-by-step instructions on how to replicate your problem and the exact commands you used, with compiler options etc.

Comment: I updated the question. That much only i did so far.

Comment: Have you got the file "flandmark_static" in the first place? It says it's missing. You still haven't shown the command and/or options you use to compile it.

Comment: it is not available in the tool itself. But i checked https://github.com/uricamic/flandmark/issues/9 where it is told that  " we have to compile the flandmark library itself. Then update the paths specified in the flandmark_compilemex.m script, to the correct paths leading to directories containing the compiled flandmark libraries. Then it should work." I don't understand what files are library files.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem for compiling flandmark . To produce Flandmark_static library ,first produce a solution using CMAKE then run the project flandmark-static. This way you do not get the warning . See if you can produce MEX files this way.